# Postgres jsonb how to check some values is not empty

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb value

```
{"mts": "375", "tele2": "", "beeline": "56", "megafon": "377"}
```

how a can check for example that mts and megafon is not empty

my query is

```
select * 
from test 
where settings->>'megafon' <> '' 
   or settings->>'mts' <> '' 
   or settings->>'beeline' <> ''
```

But it is so longer query, how to write short condition?

Comment: Do you really store keys with "empty" values, or would the keys simply not be part of the JSON? e.g. would your JSON look like this `{"mts": "", "tele2": "", "beeline": "56", "megafon": "377"}` or like this: `{"tele2": "", "beeline": "56", "megafon": "377"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM
    jsonb_each_text('{"mts": "", "tele2": "", "beeline": "56", "megafon": "377"}'::jsonb)
WHERE value != ''
```

`json_each_text()` expands every json element as text element into one row each. The result is a table with columns `key` and `value`.

Now you are able to filter the `value` column for every content.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html